# How to avoid ContextMenu after long mouse press in Firefox OS Simulator

Tags: mouse, context-menu, simulator

I installed a chat app in Firefox OS Simulator.

That app adds `contextmenu` event listeners, in which it allows me to remove individual messages.

However, that event listener prevents me from selecting text in the messages.

I don't care about how this problem is solved in touch devices. Since I am using a PC, I can dispatch a `contextmenu` event listener by clicking with the right button of my mouse.

Therefore, when I hold my left mouse button I want to get red of that `contextmenu` event, but still be able to select text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior is not a bug, it's intended as a feature:

> Simulate touch events on desktop

If you still want to disable it, follow those steps:

1. Open the profile folder of Firefox:

   1. Go to `about:support`
   2. Find the "Application Basics" section
   3. Find the "Profile Folder" entry in the table
   4. Click the "Show Folder" button
2. Go to the `extensions` subfolder
3. Find the folder of your simulator, e.g. `fxos_2_2_simulator@mozilla.org`
4. Go to `b2g/modules/devtools` subfolders
5. Open the `touch-events.js` file with a proper text editor
6. Find the `sendContextMenu` function:

   ```js
   sendContextMenu: function teh_sendContextMenu(target, x, y, delay) {
     let doc = target.ownerDocument;
     let evt = doc.createEvent('MouseEvent');
     evt.initMouseEvent('contextmenu', true, true, doc.defaultView,
                        0, x, y, x, y, false, false, false, false,
                        0, null);
     let content = this.getContent(target);
     let timeout = content.setTimeout((function contextMenu() {
       target.dispatchEvent(evt);
       this.cancelClick = true;
     }).bind(this), delay);
     return timeout;
   },
   ```
7. Comment this line to avoid dispatching the event:

   ```js
   // target.dispatchEvent(evt);
   ```
8. Restart the Simulator

Note it's important to only prevent the dispatch of the event instead of not calling `sendContextMenu`. Otherwise, the click wouldn't be cancelled (`this.cancelClick = true`), so text selection wouldn't work properly.

Answer (score 0):

This is a per app solution:

1. Find the path to the app. It will be something like

   ```
   [Firefox profile]\extensions\[Firefox OS Simulator]\profile\webapps\[ID]\application.zip
   ```
2. Backup and extract it
3. Find the JS file which adds the `contextmenu` event listener.

   Probably, it will be something like

   ```js
   someThing.addEventListener('contextmenu', function handler(event) {
     // ...
   });
   ```
4. Filter out the left mouse button:

   ```js
   someThing.addEventListener('contextmenu', function handler(event) {
     if(evt.button === 0) return;
     // ...
   });
   ```
5. Make sure the Simulator is closed
6. Insert the modified file at the right place of `application.zip`.